# Is there a technical reason why an automatic property must define both a get and set accessor

Tags: c#, accessor, automatic-properties

I know that automatic properties must define a get and set accessor method, I also know that it is possible for either of these accessors to be made invisible by means of an access modifier.

Is there a technical reason why the compiler is happy with

```
public object Property { get; set; }
```

but not

```
public object Property { get; }
```

My (possibly wrong) understanding of this code is that the compiler generates a backing field that is hidden from the calling code like so:

```
private object hiddenField; //hidden by compiler.

public object Property

{

get { return hiddenField; }

set { hiddenField = value;}

}
```

If the compiler can generate that, is there a reason that it can't omit the set accessor function based on the presence (or lack thereof) of a setter in the property declaration.

I understand that this may be an issue of feature scope rather than a technical limitation, I also freely admit that I have not yet consulted the C# language specification as yet.

[**UPDATE 2**]

Forgive me...I'm an idiot :P, I see now, thank you everyone for tollerating my senior moment/

Comment: without a way to set it what would it return?

Comment: You wouldn't be able write to the automatic property if there wasn't a `set;`.. I understand what you're saying though - why can't the compiler assume that if there isn't one, just *pretend*. If it's a problem for you that there is one, you have the option of specifying `private set;`

Comment: @kenny Yours was the comment that bought me out of my day dream about there being some way to use an auto-prop without a set. Thanks

Comment: @Cripplesmurf, you may find the get only property useful as part of an interface.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without the set accessor, there is no way to set the value, since you don't have a way to access "hiddenField".

Similarly, without a get accessor, there would be no way to get back a value you set.

Since it really becomes useless, it's not allowed.

However, you can have different accessibility on the two methods:

```
public object Property { get; private set; }
```

This provides you the ability to hide the set from outside, but still have a usable property.

Answer (score 1):

```
public object Property { get; private set; }
```

will work, and it will have the semantics you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

How could you use a property such the following?

`public object Property { get; }`

Theoritically if you could write something like that it always returns null as it lacks to the set accessor. I think it is useless unless you set the hidden field in some way to have a static value to always return it.

Answer (score 0):

From the C# spec:

> Because the backing field is
>   inaccessible, it can be read and
>   written only through the property
>   accessors, even within the containing
>   type.

Leaving one of the accessors out would mean that the property would either be read-only or write-only, even within the constructor of the class/struct.  Not very useful.